# Trigger event on chrome extension icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It is possible to trigger a click event on chrome extension icon? Like in jquery we use to do:

```
$('#blabla').trigger('click');
```

My goal: if a certain element is visible in the popup, than trigger a click event on the icon. I'm aware of the `chrome.browserAction`, but for this I have to do a click manually.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

Chrome/Chromium considers the actual user interaction a very important factor to grant certain temporary privileges to the code executed in this interaction's event handler. Like the ability to access DOM of the active tab when only `"activeTab"` permission is specified in manifest.json. Or the ability to use clipboard API and some other things.